# Description Setting and Viewing Issue

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, discord.js

I have been trying to set a Bio for my `profile` command embed that people can change. I think it should work, but there seems to be something wrong with my code.

Here is the relevant code:

```
const PREFIX = '!';
var bio = {};
client.on('message', async message => {
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'setBio':
      bio[message.author.id] = args[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
        message.channel.send('Your bio has been changed!')
            .then(msg => msg.delete(3000)); 
        break;
    case 'profile':
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle('__' + message.author.username + '\'s Profile__')
        .addField('Bio: ', bio[message.author.id])
        .setColor(message.member.colorRole.color)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
      message.channel.send(embed);
     break;
    }
});
```

Both commands now show, but now when I try to change the Bio and then show the profile, the Bio doesn't change. I checked in the console, but nothing is showing as a error. *Now it's pretty annoying.*

Comment: i dont think `args[1,2,3,...,20]` is doing what you think it's doing...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If i make an array `let a = [1,2,3,4]` and call `a[0, 1]`, i get the output `2`

Comment: does that mean that only the 20th argument would appear?

Comment: What would I have to do to make it see all args 1-20?

Comment: You could do: `let newArr = args.slice(1)` to remove the first element of the array, and save it to `newArr`, and then do `bio[message.author.id] = newArr`

Comment: It's like \n was added to every word.

Comment: every word used in the bio/arg is put on a new line, such as using \n.

Comment: add field takes a title and a value, both of type `string` (`.addField("title", "value")`). But you are trying to pass it an array. Try doing `bio[message.author.id].forEach(value => {
  embed.addField("title_here", value);
});`. This will, however, create multiple fields with each item in a subset field.

Comment: As in where? In replace of the `.addField('Bio: ', bio[message.author.id])`?

Comment: yes, remove that line, and add it before `message.channel.send`

Comment: `.setTitle('__' + message.author.username + '\'s Profile__')
      .setColor(message.member.colorRole.color)
                    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
                    bio[message.author.id].forEach(value => { embed.addField("Bio", value); });
                    message.channel.send(embed);` is this right? sorry for asking so much.

Comment: should be, but this will return 20 fields with the title "Bio". If you want to have it all under 1 field, try `.addField('Bio: ', bio[message.author.id].join(","))`, or replace the `,` with the seperator of your choosing

Comment: This fixed that problem, but the message is like 'Look,at,that!,The,bio,is,almost,done!' Oop, might fix it.

Comment: replace `.join(",")` with `.join(" ")`

Comment: oh okay I am dumb

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: I will add all of this to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that running `args[1,2,3,...,20]` will only return the last index you passed it, not the entire array with each index. You could instead replace that line with:

```
bio[message.author.id] = args.slice(1)
```

which will return the array minus the first item in it.

As for your embedding of this array, you can only pass string values into the `.addField()` method, so instead, you should join the array together into a coherent string, as such:

```
.addField('Bio: ', bio[message.author.id].join(" "))
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it to also do a error when you try viewing your profile without setting a Bio. Now to just set a database for the Bios.. I'm thinking a JSON, but I dunno

Comment: If you are looking at storing your data in JSON format, i would recommend looking into MongoDB. You can interface with MongoDB from your discord server using `mongoose`

Comment: Ok, but I'll be a tad careful, since I think I heard news before (dunno how long ago) about the security of it.

Comment: every database has security issues, its up to you to prevent invalid access of it (ie. sanitising inputs)

Comment: oof, I remember it wasn't MongoDB themselves, just some database attacks - https://www.zdnet.com/article/mongodb-databases-still-being-held-for-ransom-two-years-after-attacks-started/